# webcam not working: one or more needed gstreamer elements are missing

Tags: camera

After the latest updates of Debian 8, the webcam is not working anymore.
In particular cheese shows "there was an error playing video from webcam".
Then I tried to run it with sudo and it shows another error message: 
"one or more needed gstreamer elements are missing: cluttervideosink"
then I searched online and I found this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/450804/cheese-do-not-start-due-gstreamer-elements-are-missing-cluttervideosink

This suggests to install gstreamer1.0-clutter and remove the folder gstreamer-1.0

But when I try to implement the solution, it works just for an instant, since the folder is immediately re-created!

How to fix this? I suspect that being an outdated solution.

Something which I believe is strange is the following: the output of

```
 dmesg less | grep video
```

is very long and confused, I can post part of it:

```
[  159.090682] Modules linked in: ctr ccm msr cpufreq_stats nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd grace fscache sunrpc nls_utf8 nls_cp437 vfat fat joydev x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul jitterentropy_rng uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc sha256_ssse3 videobuf2_memops sha256_generic videobuf2_core hmac v4l2_common videodev drbg media ansi_cprng snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 iTCO_wdt asus_nb_wmi iTCO_vendor_support asus_wmi sparse_keymap ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath snd_hda_codec_conexant mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic ath3k aesni_intel cfg80211 aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper btusb btrtl btbcm btintel ablk_helper cryptd i915 efi_pstore snd_hda_intel mei_me pcspkr bluetooth drm_kms_helper psmouse evdev snd_hda_codec serio_raw drm
[  159.090741]  rfkill efivars snd_hda_core mei lpc_ich i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep mfd_core shpchp i2c_i801 wmi snd_soc_rt5640 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core dw_dmac snd_compress dw_dmac_core video snd_pcm battery snd_timer snd soundcore regmap_i2c int3402_thermal snd_soc_sst_acpi processor_thermal_device i2c_designware_platform intel_soc_dts_iosf i2c_designware_core int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone ac iosf_mbi acpi_thermal_rel processor button fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 sg sd_mod crc32c_intel ahci xhci_pci libahci xhci_hcd libata scsi_mod usbcore usb_common thermal thermal_sys sdhci_acpi sdhci i2c_hid hid mmc_core
[  159.090850]  [<ffffffffa08bf207>] ? uvc_delete+0x17/0x150 [uvcvideo]
[  159.090868]  [<ffffffffa089044a>] ? v4l2_release+0x4a/0x80 [videodev]
[  159.106724] Modules linked in: ctr ccm msr cpufreq_stats nfsd auth_rpcgss oid_registry nfs_acl nfs lockd grace fscache sunrpc nls_utf8 nls_cp437 vfat fat joydev x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp intel_rapl coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul jitterentropy_rng uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc sha256_ssse3 videobuf2_memops sha256_generic videobuf2_core hmac v4l2_common videodev drbg media ansi_cprng snd_hda_codec_hdmi arc4 iTCO_wdt asus_nb_wmi iTCO_vendor_support asus_wmi sparse_keymap ath9k ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath snd_hda_codec_conexant mac80211...
```

another output which could be useful is this, which is what happens when I run cheese from terminal without sudo:

```
(cheese:7654): cheese-WARNING **: Could not read from resource.: gstv4l2bufferpool.c(995): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin28/GstV4l2Src:video_source:
poll error 1: Invalid argument (22)


** (cheese:7654): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed

(cheese:7654): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_device_node: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:7654): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:7654): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:7654): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:7654): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

** (cheese:7654): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Edit: as it was asked in the comments

output of sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`? please edit in its output

Comment: I added the output you asked for